# PHP's extract() Function

Tags: php

If I use PHP's extract() function to import a variable from an array, will a variable with the same name be overwritten? The reason I ask is because I'm trying to initialize all of my variables.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6):

By default it will overwrite.

http://php.net/extract

> If `extract_type` [the second argument] is not specified, it is assumed to be `EXTR_OVERWRITE`

See the linked page for other options

Answer (score 4):

The default is to overwrite, however you can change this action to one of several possiblities, by telling the function how to handle collisions:

for example passing `EXTR_SKIP` as the second parameter e.g `extract($array,EXTR_SKIP)` will cause collisions to be skipped.

The full usage is detailed here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on the [extract_type value](https://www.php.net/extract) you use. The default, however, is to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the second argument you pass to the function. extract() takes an optional second argument consisting of constants. See the docs at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php